# How do I create a wildcard route (/something/*) in Silex?

Tags: routes, silex

How can I create a route like /something/* where * could be one or mode 'subfolders'? (Using Silex framework)

For example:

```
/something/foo
```

or

```
/something/foo/bar
```

The purpose: I need to replicate a Webservice and send a POST request to another URL changing 2 $_POST parameters and give it returns back. But it can have one or mode parameters after /something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick is to overwrite the default regex for a url parameter, that doesn't match `/`:

```
$app->post("/something/{the_rest})", function () {
    // do stuff
})->assert("the_rest", ".*");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I was almost there, using POSIX with assert. Thanks.

Comment: But this will not match `/something/foo/bar/test?another=1`... Any help on that?

Comment: It should match that url as well.